# CIFAR-100 - I can't find the file: "cifar100_fine_labels.json"

Tags: json, dataset, label, tensorflow-datasets

I'm a newbie and I'm making a tutorial.

I can't find the file: "cifar100_fine_labels.json"
In the tutorial, the guy already has this file (cifar100_fine_labels.json) and says you can download it from this site ([https://www.cs.toronto.edu/~kriz/cifar.html](https://www.cs.toronto.edu/%7Ekriz/cifar.html)), but I downloaded this dataset from this site: "CIFAR-10 python version" and i can't find this file.

In practice do this:

```
# I downloaded the Cifar-100 dataset:
(train_images, train_labels), (test_images, test_labels) = cifar100.load_data(label_mode='fine')

# Load the list of labels from a JSON file
import json
with open('cifar100_fine_labels.json', 'r') as fine_labels:
    cifar100_fine_labels = json.load(fine_labels)
```

and it doesn't work becouse I don't have: 'cifar100_fine_labels.json'.

Can I download it from somewhere or do I have to extract it myself from the dataset?

Thanks for the answer

I would like to get where I can find this file or how to extract it from the dataset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the link you send there are two datasets, "CIFAR-10" at the top, and when you scroll down there is "CIFAR-100". It sounds like you downloaded the first dataset, but actually need the second one.

So scroll down and download CIFAR-100 python version and the json should be there :)

Edit: After downloading the file myself I realize this might not fix your problem. Here is some code to build such a json. (provided you downloaded and unzipped the file)

```py
# from cifar link, changed for python3
def unpickle(file):
    import pickle
    with open(file, 'rb') as fo:
        dict = pickle.load(fo)
    return dict

path = "cifar-100-python/meta"

label_translation = unpickle(path)

with open("cifar100_fine_labels.json", "w") as f:
    json.dump(label_translation, f)
```

Comment: (The difference between the datasets is by the way, that the first one has 10 classes and the second one has 100 classes, thats where the name comes from)